# Animation AutoReverse = false but does it anyway and starts from the wrong starting point

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, .net-4.5

I'm trying to get an image from the bottom right corner of a canvas to the top left corner of the canvas an repeating this behavior forever. The image should never do the reverse animation from the top left corner to the top right corner. I am new with animation, so I used [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746981%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

At the moment my image is moving from the top left corner to the right bottom corner and back. I tried changing the start position of the image in the canvas, with the result, that the animation used this position as new starting point. I also tried using negative values, to get the image moving to the opposite direction. Reducing the amount of points in the segment got me a shorter animation path, but nothing else. I also set AutoReverse=false, without any changes in the animation behavior.

My ideas are,
 - The segment class is building a circle out of the points, but which other class to use?
 - The start position has to change, but how do I get the object to move up instead of down the screen?

My Code,

```
Storyboard animationSB = new Storyboard();

//Image book = createImage(model.keywordCollection[0].cover.small);
Image rope1 = createImage("pack://application:,,,/GUI;component/Resources/rope_trans.png");
rope1.Height = 360.0;
rope1.Width = 185.0;

//Transform to move the book image
TranslateTransform aniRope1 = new TranslateTransform();
this.RegisterName("AnimatedRope1", aniRope1);
rope1.RenderTransform = aniRope1;
Canvas.SetLeft(rope1, 258.659);
Canvas.SetTop(rope1, 583.212);
LeftRope.Children.Add(rope1);


//Anitmation path
PathGeometry animationPath1 = new PathGeometry();
PathFigure pathFigure1 = new PathFigure();
PolyLineSegment lineSegments1 = new PolyLineSegment();
lineSegments1.Points.Add(new Point(LeftRope.ActualWidth, LeftRope.ActualHeight));
lineSegments1.Points.Add(new Point(258.659, 583.212));
lineSegments1.Points.Add(new Point(120.596, 272.665));
lineSegments1.Points.Add(new Point(0, 0));
pathFigure1.Segments.Add(lineSegments1);
animationPath1.Figures.Add(pathFigure1);
animationPath1.Freeze();

//Animate transform to move image along the path on the x-axis
DoubleAnimationUsingPath translateXAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimationUsingPath();
translateXAnimation1.PathGeometry = animationPath1;
translateXAnimation1.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6);
translateXAnimation1.Source = PathAnimationSource.X;
translateXAnimation1.AutoReverse = false;

Storyboard.SetTargetName(translateXAnimation1, "AnimatedRope1");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateXAnimation1, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));

//Animate transform to move image along the path on the y-axis
DoubleAnimationUsingPath translateYAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimationUsingPath();
translateYAnimation1.PathGeometry = animationPath1;
translateYAnimation1.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6);
translateYAnimation1.Source = PathAnimationSource.Y;
translateYAnimation1.AutoReverse = false;

Storyboard.SetTargetName(translateYAnimation1, "AnimatedRope1");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateYAnimation1, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.YProperty));

//Create Storyboard containing and applying the animation

//animationSB.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
animationSB.Children.Add(translateXAnimation1);
animationSB.Children.Add(translateYAnimation1);

animationSB.AutoReverse = false;
```

The storyboard is started in another method.

I am developing on windows 8.1N with .Net 4.5.1 C# an desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the line:

```
lineSegments1.Points.Add(new Point(LeftRope.ActualWidth, LeftRope.ActualHeight));
```

with

```
pathFigure1.StartPoint = new Point(LeftRope.ActualWidth, LeftRope.ActualHeight);
```

It turns out that if you don't specify the StartPoint for PathFigure, it automatically closes the figure, i.e. connects last and first points from the points collection.